# How to convert .flac to .mp3 using PHP

Tags: php, mp3, converters, flac, audio

for my personal Website I'd like to implement a gadget for me and my friends.
Aim of this script should be to convert an uploaded .flac audio file to .mp3 choosing the music quality eg 128kbit/s or 320kbit/s.
Is this possible an if so, how?
Interesting is only the core part (converting), the rest I already have implement :)

Thanks very much :))
Niklas

Comment: Read [this article](http://blog.tordeu.com/?p=184)  and with `shell_exec` and your imagination, you can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with ffmpeg? If it is installed on your server, you can try running on CLI

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac output.mp3
```

If that works, you can go on trying passing that command from your application to the shell (if you use for example PHP for your application and a Debian Linux as hosting.)

To include the bitrate you can use

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -ab 128k output.mp3
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -ab 320k output.mp3
```

If you can use it, see also the documentation: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html
It is possible, that you have to use a different command for the bitrate depending on your version.